# NSNumberFormatter not allowing decimal input

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield, decimal, nsnumberformatter

If I enter a decimal point '.' into my UITextField, the number formatter called does not recognise the decimal point and continues as if the decimal point has not been entered. I.e If I entered 200.9, the decimal point would not show up in the textfield and the text of the textfield would be 2009.

I want to limit the number of digits after the decimal point to 2 as I believe I am doing below. Please can you tell me what I am doing to cause this?

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    BOOL isDeleting = [textField.text substringWithRange:range].length > string.length;
    int index = [textFields indexOfObject:textField];
    NSString *input;

    if (isDeleting == NO)
        input = [textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    else {
        NSMutableString *str = [textField.text mutableCopy];
        [str deleteCharactersInRange:range];
        input = [[str copy] autorelease];
        [str release];
    }

    if ([input isEqualToString:@"£"] || ([input isEqualToString:@""] && index != 1)) {
        [textField setText:@"£"];
    }
    else {
        if (index != 1)
            [textField setText:[self numberFormattedString:input]];
        else 
            [textField setText:input];
    }

    return NO;
}
- (NSString *) numberFormattedString:(NSString *)str {
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"£" withString:@""];
    str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""];
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
    NSLocale *locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en-UK"];
    [formatter setLocale:locale];
    [locale release];
    [formatter setAllowsFloats:YES];
    [formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
    [formatter setMinimumFractionDigits:0];
    [formatter setDecimalSeparator:@"."];
    return [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:[str floatValue]]];
}
```

TIA.

Comment: Seems ok to me, but shouldn't `setMaximumFractionDigits:` be set to 2 instead of 3 if you only want two decimal places?

Comment: Yes, it should be! Good spot :) Btw, if I enter a decimal, it is in the NSString *str when I pass it over to the -numberFormattedString: method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you enter the number 100 and then a decimal point. When numberFormattedString is called with the string `£100.`, it's going to get rid of the £, and str will contain the string `100.` which `[str floatValue]` converts to the float value 100, and finally your number formatter spits it back out as the string `£100` without any decimal point. So basically `[str floatValue]` is killing your decimal point.

One solution is to check for when you get the decimal point as your replacement string in the text field delegate method, and skip calling numberFormattedString in that case. Then when the user enters the next digit, you can carry on calling numberFormattedString, and the conversion should happen correctly. You'll just have to make sure that the user can only enter one decimal point.

EDIT: I just realized that my suggested solution still won't work if you enter a 0 after the decimal point (e.g. 100.0), but I'm sure there is a minor tweak that you can figure out to solve that.

Comment: Also FYI...the way that I have figured out the answers to the couple of questions you've had about this is to use the debugger to step through your code (after setting up a test project with it) and see where things go wrong. I'd suggest becoming familiar with the Xcode debugger if you aren't already.

Comment: I certainly am familiar with the debugger, I tracked the digits up until the -numberWithString method, I just presumed that the reason why the decimal was getting killed is because I am not setting a variable of the number formatter.

Comment: You could adjust the number formatter to enforce the existence of a decimal point, but that doesn't really work with the way you are doing things (i.e. going from string to number to string after each key press).

Comment: I'm trying to avoid enforcing the existence of the decimal, but thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSCharacterSet *numSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789."];
    NSString *newString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    int charCount = [newString length];

    if ([newString rangeOfCharacterFromSet:[numSet invertedSet]].location != NSNotFound
        || [string rangeOfString:@"."].location != NSNotFound
        || charCount > 15) {
        return NO;
    }

//    if (charCount == 4 || charCount == 9 || charCount==13) {
//         newString = [newString stringByAppendingString:@"."];
//    }
    NSLog(@"IN method");
    textField.text = newString;

    return NO;
}
```